# How to plot PCA using hellinger transformation in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, pca

I'm trying to ggplot using Hellinger Transformation on my dataset. It works fine for a regular `prcomp` function but not Hellingers. How can I plot the data from Hellinger transformed data using ggplot?

```
library(ggfortify)
library(vegan)
df <- iris[1:4]
pca_res <- prcomp(df, scale. = TRUE)
autoplot(pca_res, data = iris, colour = 
'Species',
     loadings = TRUE, loadings.colour = 'blue',
     loadings.label = TRUE, loadings.label.size = 3)

##Hellinger Transformation
df.hell <- decostand(df, method = "hellinger")
df.hell <- rda(df.hell)

ggplot2::autoplot(df.hell)

autoplot(df.hell, data = iris, colour = 
 'Species',
 loadings = TRUE, loadings.colour = 'blue',
 loadings.label = TRUE, loadings.label.size = 3)

Error: Objects of type rda/cca not supported by autoplot.

Error: Objects of type rda/cca not supported by autoplot.
```

Edit 1: Even if the first plot can be manually computed in ggplot2, what about the rest of the plots like loading, or ellipses etc? base plot allows for overlay when using Hellingers but doesn't seem like ggplot2 would directly allow for it.

Comment: see https://github.com/gavinsimpson/ggvegan for an autoplot function for rda output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`prcomp` returns an object of class `prcomp`, which can be plotted with `autoplot`. As the error message says, `rda` function returns an object of class `"rda" "cca"`, which cannot be plotted using `autoplot`. Therefore, you must extract the bits you need manually:

```
data.frame(PC = df.hell$CA$u, species = iris$Species) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x=PC.PC1, y=PC.PC2)) + 
    geom_point(aes(colour=species))
```

You can find the relevant parts of the object by doing `str(df.hell)`:

```
List of 10
 $ colsum        : Named num [1:4] 0.037 0.0746 0.086 0.0854
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:4] "Sepal.Length" "Sepal.Width" "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width"
 $ tot.chi       : num 0.0216
 $ Ybar          : num [1:150, 1:4] 0.0042 0.00511 0.0042 0.00359 0.00363 ...
  ..- attr(*, "scaled:center")= Named num [1:4] 0.656 0.479 0.498 0.267
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:4] "Sepal.Length" "Sepal.Width" "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width"
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : NULL
  .. ..$ : chr [1:4] "Sepal.Length" "Sepal.Width" "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width"
  ..- attr(*, "METHOD")= chr "PCA"
 $ method        : chr "rda"
 $ call          : language rda(X = df.hell)
 $ pCCA          : NULL
 $ CCA           : NULL
 $ CA            :List of 7
  ..$ eig    : Named num [1:4] 0.0208691 0.0005348 0.0001951 0.0000205
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:4] "PC1" "PC2" "PC3" "PC4"
  ..$ poseig : NULL
  ..$ u      : num [1:150, 1:4] -0.122 -0.11 -0.119 -0.106 -0.123 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : NULL
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:4] "PC1" "PC2" "PC3" "PC4"
  ..$ v      : num [1:4, 1:4] -0.241 -0.508 0.589 0.58 0.375 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:4] "Sepal.Length" "Sepal.Width" "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width"
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:4] "PC1" "PC2" "PC3" "PC4"
  ..$ rank   : int 4
  ..$ tot.chi: num 0.0216
  ..$ Xbar   : num [1:150, 1:4] 0.0042 0.00511 0.0042 0.00359 0.00363 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "scaled:center")= Named num [1:4] 0.656 0.479 0.498 0.267
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:4] "Sepal.Length" "Sepal.Width" "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width"
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : NULL
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:4] "Sepal.Length" "Sepal.Width" "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width"
  .. ..- attr(*, "METHOD")= chr "PCA"
 $ inertia       : chr "variance"
 $ regularization: chr "this is a vegan::rda result object"
 - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "rda" "cca"
```

[image]

Comment: I'm confused then, how do we plot the other stuff like loading + loading names etc? In baseplot you just overlay it. I thought the whole point of autoplot was that the overlay was built in?